# Run a task only when registered output (which is a list) has changed

Tags: ansible, task

I am running the below task which registers the output to a `status` variable, which is a list.

```yaml
- name: Check status before client set up
  shell: |
    curl -k -s -S -i -u logstash:logstash 'https://localhost:5665/v1/status?pretty=1'| jq  .results[0].status.api.zones.master.endpoints[0]
  register: status
- debug:
    var: status.stdout_lines
```

Which outputs:

```yaml
[
  "stage-master-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com",
  "stage-master2-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com"
]
```

Now I have the following task to run, conditionally, if the output of the above task doesn't contain the items `stage-master-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com` and `stage-master2-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com`, **or, in other words**, run the task only when the output has changed.

I tried the `find` module, but list wouldn't allow it.

Here is the taks with the condition for a better picture:

```yaml
- name: Setup client
  shell: |
    icinga2 node setup --ticket {{ticket.stdout}} \
    --cn {{agent_fqdn}} \
    --endpoint {{groups.icinga_primary_master[0]}} \
    --zone master \
    --parent_zone master \
    --parent_host {{master_ip}} \
    --trustedcert {{icinga_certs_dir}}{{icinga_master_cert_file}} \
    --accept-config \
    --disable-confd
  register: setup
  when: ???
  ##     ^-- Which condition can I use here?
```

Full debug output:

```yaml
ok: [stage-master2-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com] => {
    "status.stdout_lines": [
        "[",
        "  \"stage-master-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com\",",
        "  \"stage-master2-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com\"",
        "]"
    ]
}
```

```
 Updated debug output:
    
    2022-08-04 16:14:00  TASK [icinga : debug] **********************************************************
    2022-08-04 16:14:00  An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
    2022-08-04 16:14:00  fatal: [stage-master2-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution."}
    2022-08-04 16:14:00  

code:

- name: Check status before client set up
  shell: |
    curl -k -s -S  -u logstash:logstash 'https://localhost:5665/v1/status?pretty=1' | jq  .results[0].status.api.zones.master.endpoints
  register: status
- debug:
    var: status.stdout | from_json

Condition:

  when: >-
    status.stdout | from_json | difference([
      "stage-master-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com",
      "stage-master2-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com",
    ]) | length > 0
```

Comment: `task doesn't contain the items  or, in other words, run the task only when the output has changed.` that's completely different. To check if something has "changed" you _have to_ store the previous state. Where are you going to store it? On Nexus? On google drive? In a file? To check if something doesn't contain something, you can just check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing anything, you have to realise that you do have a string representation of a JSON array, not a JSON array.

So, in order to get a list, like you claim you have in your question, you should use:

```yaml
status.stdout | from_json
```

and not

```yaml
status.stdout_lines
```

---

There are two cases here:

1. you want to act if the items in the list are the different, but also if they come in a different order, then you can run a simple comparison of the lists

   ```yaml
   when: >-
     status.stdout | from_json != [
       "stage-master-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com",
       "stage-master2-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com",
     ]
   ```
2. you only want to act if there are new elements or elements removed from the list, regardless of the positions of the elements, then you can use the [`difference` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory)

   ```yaml
   when: >-
     status.stdout | from_json | difference([
       "stage-master-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com",
       "stage-master2-icinga.int.cloud.ruckuswireless.com",
     ]) | length > 0
   ```

---

<sup>*For further reference, the usage of `>-` is a YAML multiline construction.*

*See:*</sup>

- <sup>*[the documentation](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#65-line-folding)*</sup>
- <sup>*https://yaml-multiline.info; that allows you to play with the different multiline constructs*</sup>

Comment: I have pasted the whole debug ouput in the question.

Comment: No luck yet , it is still not satisfying the need :( I have pasted the updated debug output

Comment: This never likely ending. I hit on another error. I have updated the debug in query. Please have a look.

Comment: Hi , Any thoughts about the solution . . should I just use the string representation itself and set the same condition of !=
but in that case , if the order changes it wouldn't work right?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sure . I am here because from_json returned error. 
Lemme research. Thank you so much

Comment: Hello . . it did work finally . . I was testing it on a "test pipeline" so the json was not giving the expected output . . merged the code to the needed environment and it worked fine.
Thank you . !!